# My app has been rejected four times

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My app has been on appstore. 1 month ago, I updated and uploaded my app to appstore but it was rejected. I have read resolution center. Apple says "we noticed users are still unable to login to your app. We can not continue with review if we can not login to your app.".
"The steps to reproduce are:

1. Launch the app
2. Enter username and password information
3. Tap Login button
4. No further action taken. Users are unable to login the app."

I have look screenshot. When user tap login button, preloader appears and doesn't disappear. It just waiting response. I think the webservice doesn't response, but I have tested many times there is no problem. If apple test the app, this problem occurs(besides that 3 times). Can you explain this situation how this happens. I'm waiting your brilliant opinions and ideas.

Comment: Have you tested on a phone, from outside your network?

Comment: Adding to Nirav's suggestions, look into your webserver logs. You know what date & time your app went to apple's review. Check and see what is going on during those time. What do the error logs say. This is clearly a some sort of timing or no response generated issue to your login. Maybe try with a new login / password. This is something you have to dig through in web server logs

Answer (score 1):

1 - Put a timeout on your webservice as well as preloader to indicate there are some issues in your webservice / connectivity. This is not only useful for Apple but also important to your users who would hate to wait endlessly for the webservice to login.

2 - Also check for internet connection and alert / show the user whether internet is connected or not. Tell them to try again after some time.

3 - If there is any specific timelines when your webservice will be down, indicate that timeframe in your 'review notes' the next time you submit with Apple.